Using django-tinymce inline with its configuration
I'm using django-tinymce and have it successfully working on Django Admin fields, and fields in standard non-Admin forms, to update an object.
I'm now trying to use it "inline" and, while this submits and saves, it doesn't use django-tinymce's configuration – specified in my settings.py – like the others.
I have a Django form like this:
class TestModelInlineUpdateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = TestModel
        fields = ("description",)
        widgets = {"description": TinyMCE()}

And my template contains:
  <form method="post" id="testForm">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.media }}

    <div class="tinymce" id="inline-editor">
      {{ object.description|safe }}
    </div>

    {% for hidden in form.hidden_fields %}
      {{ hidden }}
    {% endfor %}

    <input type="hidden" name="description" value="">

    <button type="submit">Update</button>
  </form>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    tinymce.init({
      selector: '#inline-editor',
      inline: true
    });

    // Set the description field to the new HTML on form submission.
    document.querySelector("#testForm").addEventListener("submit", function(ev) {
      ev.preventDefault();
      let descriptionHTML = document.querySelector("#inline-editor").innerHTML;
      let descriptionField = document.querySelector("input[name='description']");
      descriptionField.value = descriptionHTML;
      this.submit();
    });
  </script>

I had to make up that last bit of JS, that ensures the edited HTML is copied from TinyMCE to the hidden form field and, while that works, I feel there is probably a better way?
On page load the console is showing:

SyntaxError: JSON Parse error: Unexpected identifier "undefined"

which probably isn't helping.
